# How do I continue even when a function errors?

Tags: rust

I'm using `reqwest` and `scraper` to write a simple web scraper in rust. One section of my code is given a link "next_page" that may or may not be valid. I want to try to access the link, and if there's an error, print the error and continue to the next link. Here's what I tried to do:

```rust
let next_page_response = reqwest::get(next_page).await;
let next_page_response = match next_page_response {
    Ok(response) => response,
    Err(error) => println!("WARN: Problem getting the url '{}'. \
        The error was {:?}", next_page, error),
};
```

This code is wrapped in a loop, and `next_page` changes every iteration.

This doesn't work, `rustc` gives the error `error[E0308]: 'match' arms have incompatible types`. I suppose this makes sense, in the first arm the expression becomes a `Response`, whereas in the second arm it becomes a `()`. However, if I change `println!` to `panic!`, the code compiles.

Questions:

1. How can I acknowledge an error and then just continue?
2. Why does `panic!` work when `println!` doesn't?

[Full code, for the curious](https://pastebin.com/1ABQgXEf).

Comment: What do you want the value of `next_page_response` to be in the case of an error? You can't just not assign to it, as that's not how Rust works. Variables have to have values.

Comment: [Why panic! can be used in match arms as return type?](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-why-does-panic-can-be-used-in-match-arms-as-return-unit-type/27654) - tldr; panicking hijacks the normal control flow and therefore it uses the *never* type to indicate that a value will not ever be returned (and within the type system is assignable to any other type).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I thought about using some kind of "error" value (I'm coming from a C/C++ background... is there something like NULL or nullptr in rust?) but the thing is then I lose the opportunity to print the exact error that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you allude to in the original post, the issue is that the return values of the two branches don't match. And as kmdreko mentions `panic!` works since it has a return type that can be used anywhere.

So if you want to avoid the panic you need to make the return values from each branch match.

One way is to have both arms return `()`.  The code can be pretty simple if you put the processing of the successful response into the body of the match.

```
pub fn process_response(response: &Response) {
    // ...
}

for next_page in pages {
    let next_page_response = reqwest::get(next_page).await;
    match next_page_response {
        Ok(response) => process_response(response),
        Err(error) => println!("WARN: Problem getting the url '{}'. \
             The error was {:?}", next_page, error),
    };
}
```

An alternate is to have both arms return an `Option` that you use later.
(In this case, it makes the code longer and uglier in my opinion, but there can be cases where it is useful). It could look something like this:

```
pub fn process_response(response: &Response) {
    // ...
}

for next_page in pages {
    let next_page_response = reqwest::get(next_page).await;
    let next_page_response = match next_page_response {
        Ok(response) => Some(response),
        Err(error) => {
             println!("WARN: Problem getting the url '{}'. \
                 The error was {:?}", next_page, error);
             None
        }
    };

    if let Some(response) = next_page_response {
        process_response(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is one of these more like the idiomatic rust style? I get the impression I need to separate my code into smaller functions, but I'm just starting to learn rust and just getting my code to compile has been so much work that I haven't even looked at functions :)

Comment: I'd go with the first approach unless there was some other constraint that required the second.

Comment: I'd add another alternative: keep it as a `Result` instead of switching to `Option` and do `if let Err(error) = next_page_response` to print.

Comment: The first approach necessitates returning `()`, right? So I can't return something else?

Comment: Your code doesn't really contain enough info about what is being returned, or what you want to return - so I haven't included anything here either.